Extracting amino acid sequence from WGS data
I would like to know, given a dataset of WGS data, what tools can I use to identify the coding regions within the DNA sequence and then convert them into amino acid sequences?

Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. Please note the homework policy. Because this is a very basic bioinformatics question it is something that your supervisor or other person in your lab, or any basic text should be able to answer.
